# getProjection cannot be resolved to a field. API V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In all my other projects im able to call getProjection() on any MapView object.  This project is different for some reason... is it because im using the new APIv2 for google maps?  any ideas?

```
package com.example.proximitystuff;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapView map =null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);

        MapView map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);

        //this line of code wont work... says projection cannot be resolved or is not a field
        Projection projection= map.getProjection;

        }


    @Override   
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            Point p = new Point(x, y);
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //todo
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: //todo
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   //todo

            }
            return false;       
        }


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
GoogleMap googleMap = map.getMap();
Projection projection = googleMap.getProjection();
```

Also replace `MapActivity` with `Activity` and remove `isRouteDisplayed`. Then start reading on Google Maps Android API v2 here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Can you explain how you knew that a GoogleMap object was needed instead of the MapView as in the old Maps api?

Comment: @adamkim From the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map